# How to loop over an array of data that saved to a JSONObject and put it in a JSONArray?

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring-boot, object

I have fields in my HTML, say for example 2 rows of fields which I loop over on my controller.

I want it to result to something like this:

```
{
"specifications":
[
    {
      "name" : "height",
      "value" : "cm"
    },
    {
      "name" : "weight",
      "value" : "kg"
    }
  ]
}
```

But every time I loop using my code below, I only get the last row of the iteration saved to my JSONArray

```
JSONObject itemTypeObj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray itemTypeArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject itemTypeSpecs = new JSONObject();
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList();

        for(int x = 0; x < specName.length; x++){

            itemTypeSpecs.put("specName", specName[x]);

            if (specValue[x].contains(",")) {

                for (String v : specValue[x].split(",")) {
                    values.add(v.trim());
                }

                itemTypeSpecs.put("specValue", values);
            } else {
                itemTypeSpecs.put("specValue", specValue[x]);
            }

            values.clear();

            itemTypeArray.put(itemTypeSpecs);

        }

itemTypeObj.put("specifications", itemTypeArray);
```

Result becomes like this instead of the one I expect from above

```
{"specifications":
  [
   {
    "name":"Weight",
    "value":"kg"
   },
   {
    "name":"Weight",
    "value":"kg"
   }
  ]
}
```

I can't find the reason why it's only getting the last row. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you should add your input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should crate array list and JSONObject inside first "for loop".Because you change always same objects Can yo try this?

```
        JSONObject itemTypeObj = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray itemTypeArray = new JSONArray();

        for (int x = 0; x < specName.length; x++) {
            List<String> values = new ArrayList();
            JSONObject itemTypeSpecs = new JSONObject();
            itemTypeSpecs.put("specName", specName[x]);

            if (specValue[x].contains(",")) {
                for (String v : specValue[x].split(","))
                    values.add(v.trim());
                itemTypeSpecs.put("specValue", values);
            } else {
                itemTypeSpecs.put("specValue", specValue[x]);
            }
            itemTypeArray.put(itemTypeSpecs);
        }
        itemTypeObj.put("specifications", itemTypeArray);
```

Comment: I tried this and it seems to get the result I needed so I'm accepting this as the answer to my question. Thank you so much! :)